# Add column to sql table with c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello I got a big problem I am trying to add a new column to my MSSQL Database Table and i tried it like thousand times but it wont work.
My destination is to press a button then use the function "eventsspalte_Hinzufügen" to add a new column with the name thats Inserted by the user.

This is the snippet.

```
private void eventsspalte_Hinzufügen()
{

    SQL_eingabe = "ALTER TABLE Teilnahmen_Events ADD @tbName bit NOT NULL ;"; //  CONSTRAINT strconst3 DEFAULT 0

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = SQL_eingabe;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbName", tb_Eventname.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The Exception says that `cmd.ExecuteQuery()` is not able to Execute the sql Command because of the wromg Syntax at @tbName I also tried to use a variable like:

```
ALTER TABLE Teilnahmen_Events ADD'"+ tb_Eventname.Text +"'bit NOT NULL ;";
```

but it also didnt work... 
I hope you got an solution for me thank you very much.

Comment: When it didnt work - what was the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot pass column name as parameter.

In your second example, single quotes are not needed, so change it into

```
ALTER TABLE Teilnahmen_Events ADD "+ tb_Eventname.Text +" bit NOT NULL ;";
```

Comment: thank you very much !! i just sit here for 2 days like the stupid retard I really am ...